# Wick's contractions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, wick-theorem

According to Wick's theorem, we have
$${\left\langle {T\left[ {\hat A\hat B\hat C\hat D} \right]} \right\rangle _0} =   {\left\langle {T\left[ {\hat A\hat B} \right]} \right\rangle _0}{\left\langle {T\left[ {\hat C\hat D} \right]} \right\rangle _0} + {\left\langle {T\left[ {\hat A\hat C} \right]} \right\rangle _0}{\left\langle {T\left[ {\hat B\hat D} \right]} \right\rangle _0} + {\left\langle {T\left[ {\hat A\hat D} \right]} \right\rangle _0}{\left\langle {T\left[ {\hat B\hat C} \right]} \right\rangle _0}$$
where $T$ is the time-ordering operator.

Getting all contractions on the right-hand side becomes a tedious task for a longer string of operators. Is there any software that generates possible combinations of these contractions quickly?

Comment: Well, the Wick theorem gives you a straightforward way to deduce all the possible contractions: just do all the possible contractions.

Comment: depending on the context this will just correspond to the series expansion of an exponential (collecting terms by order) though this really depends on the types of objects you have here.

Comment: So to be clear, you're looking for something that can generate the set of pairs as a text-string? Or do you want it to do the computation as well?